# dynamic jQuery selector not working, when id is concatenated

Tags: jquery

The following selector is working,

```
var control = $('select[id^="Control0"]')[0];
```

When I use the below selector, its not working.

```
var index = 0;
var control = $('select[id^="Control' + index + '"]')[0];
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: could you post html as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. We will need to see your html to help any further.

Here's how I tested your code: `

```js
var index = 0;
var control = $('select[id^="Control' + index + '"]')[0];

alert($(control).text())
```

```html
<select id="Control0">
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

`